# Stop raspberry pi from turning on when plugged in

Tags: power, home-automation

I am planning to use raspberry pi in an embedded design. Is there any way i can prevent the pi from automatically turning on when plugged in?

Comment: Add a mosfet/relay/power-transistor to the power input.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Rev 2 Raspberry Pi you should have a P6 header, which is intended for a reset switch.

I would imagine if you held the board in reset from before powering up (the pins shorted) it should prevent it from booting up until you release it from reset (disconnect the pins).

This will require a small amount of electronics, I assume this is not a problem if it is for an embedded application.

[eLinux - P6 header](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals#P6_header)

Comment: Can anyone confirm this, don't want to damage my pi.

Comment: Good idea - just the implications... Nearly everywhere I look gives the indication that only momentarily shorting the pins are a good idea - Have you tried this yourself @PiBorg?

Comment: I have not, usually with other devices this is connecting a reset line (with a weak pull-up) to ground, which will prevent the chips starting. In the event the chip has started this reset line going low triggers an internal reset which would then wait of the line to go high again (remove the short) before starting.

Answer (score 0):

keeping that pin shorted is a bad idea for the Pi and the power supply(it puts a load on it causing heat).

you need to build a software switch for power on if your intent is to use it with other devices that would turn it on (done by a relay to control power to the main port) or hard wire a actual switch for the power.